# 2 tables select, table A is reference to table B

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables A & B. A contains reference number and has only 6 rows with one column as `job_id`, `name_of_job`, `description`, etc. While B contains results of job such as `time_of_job` was carried out.

E.g.

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJjuL.png)

[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Lxq.png)

I wish to select Table A but with the total time as according to Table B like this

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCdLX.png)

What would be the MySQL statements, please any help would be wonderful.

Thanks

Comment: please provide a better database schema so that we could help you better

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: In Table B, you have several references to `job_id` of table A, so what do you mean by total time- the sum of each job time in a single row?? Please clarify this. But your example is not showing it as summed up in 3rd image that's why I am confused.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your comment. I really appreciate it. I do understand the purpose of Stack Overflow and I have done different ways to solve it, but did not really achieve what I wish to achieve. That is the reason why I post here !!! If I post what I have so far, the codes, it will confuse a lot of people and programmer. I think my question is clear . . .

Comment: Your question may be clear, but it shows no effort to solve the problem yourself. If you've *done different ways to solve it*, you should be able to include at least one of those *ways to solve it* in your post. *What would be the statements* is not a *way to solve it*. We are not a code writing service. Read my previous comment again.

Comment: @KenWhite since you are an admin... you can delete this post....Theres no way you could do it in a different way but to write an sql statement, how else can you solve such approach as my question....My effort . . .you have no idea about my effort and how much I have put to it....YOUR Answer states that you do not want to put forth ANY EFFORT :::::

Comment: Continuing to be rude isn't going to help you here. Please read my first comment again. It's not going to do you much good to get blocked from asking questions here or getting your account suspended.

Comment: I think your comment was rude too. . . Perhaps read your first comment....

Comment: *you have no idea about my effort and how much I have put to it.* -- only you can fix that problem.  I enjoy helping people out, but all I see here is some links.  Take the time to type it out in the editor.  Sometimes the time it takes to explain the problem to someone else will make the solution obvious.

Comment: OK. Suit yourself. I've tried to help you several times, but clearly you're more interested in arguing and being difficult than you are in getting help. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the comments any way . . Good luck to yours....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

SUM time_of_jobs group by `job_id`

```
SELECT
  a.job_id,
  sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(time_of_jobs))) AS total
FROM TableA a,
     TableB b
WHERE a.job_id = b.job_id
GROUP BY a.job_id;
```

[image: totaltime]